# AngularJS + SPA - change layout

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, single-page-application

I build a SPA using AngularJS. I want to have two diffrent layouts for page and for admin dashboard.

My current index.html looks like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="AngularApp">
<head>
....
</head>
<body>
<div>
//some code for navbar and others stuff that doesn't change
</div>
    <div data-ng-view="">
//here are loaded all the content
    </div>
```

I want to do a diffrent page with diffrent content and navbar for admin.
How can I switch to a completely different layout with different css, js etc.
Basically a second index-admin.html that will load angular, bootstrap, js, css and everything from the top
any ideas?
setting routing like this

```
    .when("/admin", {
        controller: "adminController",
        templateUrl: "/app/admin/views/index.html"
    });
```

will load content into

```
 <div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

which I do not want

Comment: You want the admin dashboard to-not be part of your angular app?

Comment: it will use angular as well, I can create second angular-app if it helps

Comment: You need to decide on a strategy, you can have nested views on same app or different pages that simulates 2 separate apps

Comment: I would like a second option, but I can't create second .Web project cause i have limited ports on server...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

There is support for nested views that will allow you to have a base view for the admin user that has a different layout